# How to make Devise redirect after confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I create an after-confirmation redirect in Devise?

Before I added the `confirmation module` the custom `after_sign_up_path` worked fine for the first time `login/signup` but now when I click the confirmation link in the email it redirects to the path I set for the after-login path (user profile).

My goal is to create a form wizard and "getting started" page to collect additional information. The obvious caveat being that this redirect will only happen one time, upon confirmation.

I tried some other solutions that have been posted on Stack Overflow but none of them seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Essentially, you want to change around [line 25](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L25) of Devise's `ConfirmationsController`.

This means you need to override the `show` action modifying the "happy path" of that `if` statement in the `show` action to your heart's content:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to confirmation_getting_started_path }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
end
```

And a scoped route for it (I put the view and action in the registrations controller but you can change it to whatever):

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
devise_scope :user do
  get '/confirmation-getting-started' => 'registrations#getting_started', as: 'confirmation_getting_started'
end
```

The default `show` action is referring to the protected `after_confirmation_path_for` method, so as another option, you could just modify what that method returns.

Comment: If I add a confirmations_controller.rb to my app does that override the one devise provides? Otherwise, how would I edit the one supplied by Devise?

Comment: Yes, you're overriding Devise's ConfirmationsController so you can make your own changes...which I thought is what you were trying to do.  Also, see my edit to my answer...I forgot the addition to the routes file where you specify that you're using your own ConfirmationsController. Good luck!

Comment: Well, you are only overriding the methods/actions you define. Any methods you don't touch get sent to Devise::ConfirmationsController.

Answer (score 141):

A less intrusive way of achieving this might be just overriding the `after_confirmation_path_for` method of `Devise::ConfirmationsController`.

Create a new `confirmations_controller.rb` in `app/controllers` directory:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  private

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    your_new_after_confirmation_path
  end

end
```

In `config/routes.rb`, add this line so that Devise will use your custom `ConfirmationsController`. This assumes Devise operates on `users` table (you may edit to match yours).

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }
```

Restart the web server, and you should have it.

Comment: @azure_ardee That's not true. This new hash syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9 and works fine for newer Ruby versions

Comment: Thanks for this. I wonder why those basic paths can't be defined trough devise configuration...

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: This IS the best answer. June 13th, 2015 and this answer still works!

Comment: Here is the actual original code, up to date https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L40

Answer (score 19):

Have you checked the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29)? It explains how to do this, with the `after_signup_path_for` being the path to define in your case.

From the wiki:

> Make a new controller "registrations_controller.rb" and customize the appropriate method:
>
> ```
> class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
>   protected
>
>   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
>     '/an/example/path'
>   end
> end
> ```

Then add a route to use it:

> Modify config/routes.rb to use the new controller
>
> ```
> devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
> ```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the redirect to happen after creating the account, but before the confirmation? Than you should set `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`. It's in the Devise wiki page I linked to, but just in a little line between examples, easy to miss (it took me a while to figure this out when I needed it...).

Comment: Here is the reference to the `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` that mentions Niels: [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration))

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by  @Lee Smith is working perfectly but I wish to add a little addition: We don't need to add the `new` and `create` actions while overriding the Devise confirmations controller for this case:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to your_desired_redirect_path }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the route file, just add routing for the confirmations controller.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: "confirmations" }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just went through all of this and none of the other answers worked (2015-04-09 with devise 3.4.1).

After signup, I wanted the user to be redirected to the login page with a message about a confirmation email. To get that working, here's what I had to do:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

protected
  # This is the method that is needed to control the after_sign_up_path 
  # when using confirmable. 
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_session_path
  end

end
```

---

I just found this comment which would have sent me exactly where I needed to be much sooner.

> Here is the reference to the after_inactive_sign_up_path_for that
>   mentions Niels: [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) –  marrossa Nov 13 '12 at 3:38

Comment: undefined local variable or method `not_confirmed_path' for #<User:0x00007fbfd9c2a7b8>

Answer (score -3):

The `confirmation_path` also must be configured while working with **refinerycms** integrated in a rails app

Comment: What does refinerycms have to do with this question?