# How to redirect to the Devise login page after user requests new confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise, confirmation

How would I redirect to the login page *after* the user has requested a new confirmation email to be received?

This is *not* the case where the user logs in for the first time after confirmation like discussed on Stack Overflow. This is about a non-confirmed, not logged-in user requesting a new confirmation email because they did not receive it.

- User goes to `/users/confirmations/new`.
- submits form.
- The same form gets shown again.

Instead I want it to go to the `login_path` after submit.

I overruled the confirmations controller, but how do I hook into Devise and make it redirect to `login_path`?

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  layout :resolve_layout


  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    redirect_to login_path
  end

end
```

Comment: Duplication. You might grep the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926626/devise-redirect-after-confirmation

Comment: @KarstenS. No, this is not the same! This refers to *after* you login. In my case the user has never logged in and just requests a confirmation again ( one send by default on registration) because it was not received. I updated the post to me even more clear on this

Comment: I see. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set this path with the following code inside your `confirmations_controller`:

```
def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for
    login_path # or whatever you want
end
```

However, the default is to redirect to `new_session_path(resource_name)` which does exactly what you want and so it does for my app.

Maybe it depends on the version of Devise.