# How to redirect to some other page after user confirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, confirmation

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and Devise 3.2.4. After user registration, the confirmation link is generated:

```
localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=HpPHitLtV3CnLy2z1ZmQ
```

I want to redirect to the `mentors/new` action after clickin on the confirmation link, but after confirmation it redirects to `/users/sign_in` which I don't want.

This is my code so far:

Routes:

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => 'confirmations' }
```

Created Confirmations controller and overrides from Devise::ConfirmationsController:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  protected

def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  if resource.has_role? :user
    redirect_to new_mentor_path("account_id")
  else
    root_path
  end
end
end
```

In ConfirmationsController, maybe I have to add some extra code.

In application controller I have this code which takes me to the `mentor/student` home after a successfull sign-in:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
  if current_user.user_type == "mentor"
    home_mentors_path(:account_id => current_user.account_id)
  else
    home_students_path(:account_id => current_user.account_id)
  end
end
```

end

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  root_path
end
```

Generally the logic is like this, but I do not understand how to do this with Devise:

```
def activate
  @user = User.where("activation_code = ?","#{params[:id]}").first
  if !@user.blank?
   if @user.created_at < 24.hours.ago
     if @user and @user.activate
      cookies[:user_id]=@user.id
      if @user.user_type == "student"
        redirect_to new_student_path
      else
        redirect_to new_mentor_path
      end
    else
      @user.destroy
      redirect_to "/"
    end
  else
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to "/"
  end
else
  redirect_to "/"
end
```

end

Comment: Looks like the `sign_in` redirect means you're not signed in after confirmation? Can you confirm your new users are signed in after they've confirmed?

Comment: Similar to your questions with two valid solutions can be found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926626/devise-redirect-after-confirmation

Comment: @RichPeck: yes user is confirmed, i have logged in as well. I just want after confirmation, without login, it should go to mentors/new page.

Comment: How do you know they are logged in? I always presumed that Devise took logged in users from `sign_in` page to another page if they are already authenticated?

Comment: @WilliamWright: Before posting my question, i checked that url too, but still issue is there.

Comment: @sivrj is this all you have in confirmation controller, if not then please post full confirmations controller

Comment: @RichPeck: How do you know they are logged in? After confirmation link clicked we can find user and store them in cookies then it is possible to know who is login and there are many more logic to know that. But i need some better solution.

Comment: I would personally use the `user_signed_in?` helper in the layout - to see if they are logged in or not. This will show you whether they're authenticated or not

Comment: I can write a quick answer if you'd like me to detail what I'd be looking at ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Devise GitHub repository](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb), this method is called when you click on the confirmation link:

```
# GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
  yield resource if block_given?

  if resource.errors.empty?
    set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
  end
end
```

Now you have overriden Devise's `after_confirmation_path` method:

```
protected
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  if resource.has_role? :user
    redirect_to new_mentor_path("account_id")
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

which is fine and Devise will redirect to your `new_mentor_path` but inside your Mentor controller you would have a `before` filer to check for authentication, something like:

```
before_action :authenticate_user! #this will check if your user is signed in or not and if not it'll redirect you
```

So as @Rich Peck suggested, you basically need to override your `show` action also so that your user is signed in before being redirected to your `new_mentor_path`.

In your `show` action you can do something like this to make sure your user is signed in:

```
# GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

  if resource.errors.empty?
    set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource)
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
  end
end
```

Also, I noticed in your `after_confirmation_path` you have

```
redirect_to new_mentor_path("account_id")
```

Why are you passing `account_id` as a string in your path?

If your `account_id` is an integer then you'll have to first set it inside the `show` action and then call your `after_confirmation_path` like

```
respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource, account_id) }
```

Also you'll have to change the definition of `after_confirmation_path` like:

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource, account_id)
  if resource.has_role? :user
    redirect_to new_mentor_path(account_id)
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: resources :mentors , :path =>"/:account_id/mentors" do, i have used in routes. account_id is string which is combination of many things taken from mentors/new. I will give a try, thank you.

Comment: Actually this script help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After research, I am posting the correct answer for the question:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

if resource.errors.empty?
  set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource)  #This will detect if user is logged in.

  respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
else
  respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
 end
end

protected
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)

  if resource.is_a?(User)
   new_mentor_path("account_id") #do not provide redirect_to which is already taken in respond_with_navigational(resource)
  else
   root_path
  end
 end  
end
```

I commented out `devise_for :users`, because this route was being called every time when clicking on the confirmation link and the confirmation controller was not being called and redirecting to the sign-in path. This is the main solution for the issue I faced:

```
# devise_for :users
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => 'confirmations' }
```

Comment: Your answer looks same as mine :)

Comment: @Mandeep: Answer is not same. I had used devise_for :users two times which was problem. I did mistake in routes, after commenting it, problem resolved by doing some modification.

Comment: @Mandeep: I upvote you since i tried to get solution from your answer and it solved. In my answer, I have explained clearly all the issue and solution of them, which i faced, which is important i think. So you can upvote me :)

Comment: Please don't post answers unless you intend for them to be _the_ selected answer. You confuse others if you are reiterating other answers. See "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)".