# Is user just confirmed in Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, device

Using device the user just confirms his email and is directed to the sign in page.

"Your account was successfully confirmed. Sign in to continue."

is displayed.

How could I check if the user was just confirmed and show an render an additional partial only for just confirmed users?

Edit: Just to make clear - I am searching for ways to do the check in the view itself and the view is devise/sessions/new.html.erb.
So I image something like:

```
<% if user was just confirmed %>
 <%= render "the_special_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

Currently I can implement this as

```
<% if flash[:notice] && flash[:notice].index("Your account was successfully confirmed. Sign in to continue.") %>
    <%= render :partial=>"special_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

But we all know how ugly this is.

The "Already answered questions" redirects the user to a new page. I would like to do the check in the same page.

Comment: It is different from the duplicated

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Comment: You could check `user.confirmed_at` field. If it's not nil, then he's confirmed. Check if it's recent too.

Comment: But I still don't have the user since he is not signed it? current_user returns nil?. He has just confirmed and is not redirected to signing in

Comment: Is this about something called "Device" or about "Devise"?

Comment: sorry, a type here. It is about Devise...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add an attribute called 'welcomed' (or so) to the User model. This is a booelan and its default is false.

If the user clicks the link in his mail, you can parse the URL whether there is a confirmation token or not. If there is a token && 'welcomed' == false, then you show the welcome partial of new.html. While your controller sends the command to create the confirmed_at - date in the User model, you set 'welcomed' to true.

So clicking the confirmation link a second time will prevent the welcome partial and just show the normal login page.

Comment: Of course this is possible. But it would require changes in the model, in the db, in the controller and in the view.  Quite a lot would I say. I think that because the flash message is already there there should be a much more easier way to check if a user was just confirmed.

Comment: Have you tried the linked solution on the right sidebar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926626/devise-redirect-after-confirmation?lq=1

Comment: That what my edit on the question is - to say that I do not want to redirect the users. I would like to render a particular partial on the page for sign_in based on whether they are new.

Comment: The solution in the linked post moves your if condition from the view to the controller. You must not need the redirection.