# Rails Devise how to set confirmation_url if using Tenants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, acts-as-tenant

I have a Rails app using Devise and it also uses acts_as_tenant.

In my applications controller I create a variable for the url (including the tenant prefix). It's called $request_url

The issue is that the URL in the confirmation email doesn't change the Tenant prefix.  For instance **some**.website.com vs **other**.website.com

How do I change this line to use that correct URL? :

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Do I need to create a new route?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying, though, that you'd like to change where they land after confirmation? I would think you still want them to go through the confirmation controller so their account becomes enabled. If you *are* saying that you'd like to change where they land after being confirmed, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115558/226574).

**As an aside**

`$request_url` would be a global variable - [those are often dangerous](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) unless you fully understand the implications. Are you setting it in a `before_filter`? You could just use and instance variable like so: `@request_url = "some string"`

Comment: The issue is the URL in the confirmation email doesn't take into consideration the Tenant prefix.  For instance, some.website.com vs other.website.com

Comment: Is there any way you can let the confirmation be handeld by devise _outside_ the tenant prefix (like it sounds like it currently is) then have this `after_confirmation` put them on the tenant? That's how I'd normally recommend tenant-scoped apps like yours.