# Gitlab email confirmation redirect

Tags: ruby, redirect, devise, gitlab

By default Gitlab redirects the user to the home page after email confirmation. I want to redirect off-site instead.

I don't think there is a config option for this so I'm asking how to hack it.

I found `confirmations_controller.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  include AcceptsPendingInvitations

  def almost_there
    flash[:notice] = nil
    render layout: "devise_empty"
  end

  protected

  def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource)
    users_almost_there_path
  end

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    accept_pending_invitations

    # incoming resource can either be a :user or an :email
    if signed_in?(:user)
      after_sign_in(resource)
    else
      Gitlab::AppLogger.info("Email Confirmed: username=#{resource.username} email=#{resource.email} ip=#{request.remote_ip}")
      flash[:notice] = flash[:notice] + " Please sign in."
      new_session_path(:user, anchor: 'login-pane')
    end
  end

  def after_sign_in(resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

How do I make it redirect me to google.com?

Comment: just override the return for the `after_confirmation_path_for` method in your code.

Comment: What do you want the new confirmation path to be?

Comment: I'm updating the tags, because your question is a Devise question. GitLab uses that gem for authentication.

Comment: @UpvoteMe send it to say google.com?

Comment: "Previously accepted answer no longer works." Is the new behavior the same as the original behavior? AFAIK Amin's answer should still work. Any more information on what is happening would be helpful.

Comment: You need to make sure you are pointing to the controller which has the overwritten `after_confirmation_path_for` method. Here's a more full-featured article on the topic if you have not already seen it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115558/5273239

Comment: @Matthew because it's Gitlab and not something I wrote myself I'm not really sure what's going on. confirmations_controller.rb itself doesn't seem to be much changed. How do I check to see if after_confirmation_path_for is being called?

The new behavior is after confirmation you're looking at the gitlab login page instead of the redirect.

Comment: Did you ask the author(s)? How about add the ability to their code and submit a patch?

Comment: _WHY_ does a previously accepted answer no longer work? Your question is drifting if the answer stopped working, which means you need to ask a new question, not insist on new answers. See these discussions on meta: "[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/153968)"
"[Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188625/153968)"
"[Are questions by default permitted to evolve, and if so, to what extent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310189/128421)"

Comment: @theTinMan It's literally still the same question, I haven't even edited it in any way or added onto it. Just the previous answer no longer works. As for why I don't know, hoping someone on SO would. Gitlab releases monthly and I updated with 7 months of patches. This is a hack and not an official feature so there's no documentation or anything on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return from the `after_confirmation_path_for` method. Here's an example for Google.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  ...

  protected


  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    ...
    'https://www.google.com' # assuming you're redirecting to Google
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this worked at the time of your answer and after updating to 12.6 it no longer works unfortunately. Any idea  how to fix it?

Comment: After updating your code it's not fair to take away a selected answer. If something changed, the question changed, and that's not the fault of the person answering. Instead a new question needs to be created with all new information. See the linked pages in my comment above.

Comment: Upvoted to ensure Amin gets at least half the bounty, despite the fact that this answer should be accepted. (and thus granted the entire bounty)

Comment: @theTinMan I thought SO was supposed to be a repository of true documentation. If I accept this someone coming here from google wouldn't get a correct answer despite it working at the time.

Comment: @Harry No, it isn't. It's supposed to be about asking **one** question that applies to you and receiving answers based on that one question. It is decidedly not about asking a question, getting an accurate and correct answer, then changing your codebase in such a way that invalidates the answer. The only problem with this answer is that you moved the goalposts AFTER asking your question and receiving the answer.

Comment: @Harry "true documentation"? At the time it was true. Truth can change as software evolves but that doesn't mean we nullify all previous true answers as that happens. At the time it was correct. You moved on but your question _should_ have remained the same, and, as a result the correctness of the answer would remain.

Comment: @anothermh not my codebase, everyone's codebase changed. Everyone coming here would be seeing the wrong answer that would waste their time and cause them frustration if this were still accepted. That's not the user experience SO wants to provide.

Comment: @theTinMan the question didn't change as you can see from the question I never edited it. The answer no longer works because it's 2020 and the relevant apis or whatever are different. This happens ALL THE TIME and answers are expected to keep up or become new ones. If I asked another question it would be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a custom confirmation controller? If not create a new confirmations_controller.rb in app/controllers directory:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to your_desired_redirect_path }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
end
```

In `config/routes.rb`, add this line so that Devise will use your custom `ConfirmationsController`. This assumes Devise operates on users table (you may edit to match yours).

`devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'confirmations' }`

The answer link : [How to make Devise redirect after confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926626/how-to-make-devise-redirect-after-confirmation)

Comment: Thanks in `config/routes.rb` it looks like there's 2 new lines:
`# Sign up
  get 'users/sign_up/welcome' => 'registrations#welcome'
  patch 'users/sign_up/update_registration' => 'registrations#update_registration'` I don't know if the ConfirmationsController is custom. I just edited the one I found in `app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb`. Maybe these 2 new lines overwrites it?

Comment: If you wish to override you could do this.